# python does not run codes for multiple inputs/variables

Tags: python

just started coding and i cant really figure out why aren't all my lines running on python compliers.

my code below-

```
myAddress = input ("3928392")
myNameAunt = input ("amanda")
print (myNameAunt, myAddress)
```

only one input gets displayed even if I write the print command separately. somehow only the first print command is run but the rest stay null

Comment: You only have one print command, and it's after both of the inputs. Do you realize that `input()` actually requires user input? As in, it pauses the program and waits for you to type something in and press enter, before continuing. In your program, it should do this twice.

Comment: Hi @Kabir, please check [Python 3 input()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) for the usage of function `input`,

Comment: You aren't getting to the execution of the print command yet. `myAddress=input("3928392")` prompts the user for an input with the prompt "3928392", and then whatever the user types until they press <Enter> will be stored in the variable `myAddress`

Comment: I suspect you don't really need `input()`. Just `myAddress = "3928392"` and `myNameAunt = "amanda"`